# ¿Cómo puedo volver a una activity si el usuario no realiza ninguna acción (evento) pasado un tiempo?

Tags: android-studio

Estoy desarrollando una app y mis conocimientos aún no son muy avanzados, me gustaría saber si podrían darme alguna solución para que, pasado un tiempo sin que el usuario haya realizado acción (evento) , se lanzara una activity (p.e la de inicio). Uso android studio, muchas gracias!!

Lo más que me he acercado es a establecer un tiempo determinado para que se lance la activity principal, pero mi idea es que ese tiempo empiece a contar desde que el usuario deja de interactuar con la interfaz. Usando el método handler.

```
  handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())

    handler.postDelayed({
             var intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
             startActivity(intent)
    }, 60000)
```

Comment: tiene que colocar un ejemplo de lo que has intentado hacer , y explicar un poco mas, para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida

Comment: Si lo que quieres es que tenga el mismo efecto que presionar el botón de volver, tienes que llamar la función `finish` en lugar de iniciar de nuevo una actividad. Creo que esto te puede ayudar https://stackoverflow.com/a/32068607/13419694

Answer (score 1):

Muchas gracias Mateo!! ya lo he resuelto, he establecido 60 segundos de inactividad por parte del usuario para que se lance la activity de inicio.

(Dentro de onCreate) :
handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())

```
    r = Runnable { // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        var intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
    startHandler()
```

(Fuera del método onCreate):

```
override fun onUserInteraction() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onUserInteraction()
    stopHandler() //stop first and then start
    startHandler()
}

fun stopHandler() {
    handler.removeCallbacks(r)
}

fun startHandler() {
    handler.postDelayed(r, 60000) //for 5 minutes
}
```